# Authorization checks with Spring & Jobrunr

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jobrunr

I'm creating an app with 4 roles. I don't have permissions stored in my database, just the roles.

At the controller level, I restrict my routes only to certain roles, for example :

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
```

And in my service's methods, I did a more thorough check as needed.

However, the problem I have with having authorization conditions in my services is that it only works if the `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` is not null.

And I realized that this could be the case, for example, in one of my jobs with Jobrunr.

So I inject my service into my job and I want to call a method, but it crashes because it can't retrieve the authenticated user.

Is there a way to manually authenticate a user in the job, is this a good way to do it?

---

**Update following @Ken Chan's reply - code not working :**

Jobrunr job :

```java
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class InactiveUsersEmail implements JobRequest {
    private Integer userId;

    @Override
    public Class<InactiveUsersEmailHandler> getJobRequestHandler() {
        return InactiveUsersEmailHandler.class;
    }
}
```

Run it using `DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable`:

```java
Stream<DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable> jobs = this.userService
    .findAll()
    .map(user -> {
        Runnable task = () -> new InactiveUsersEmail(user.getId());
        return new DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable(task, this.authorizationComponent.getSecurityContext());
    });

// here not working: 
// cannot resolve method 'enqueue(java.util.stream.Stream<org.springframework.security.concurrent.DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable>)'
BackgroundJobRequest.enqueue(jobs);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `Runnable` that is submitted to Jobrunr by [`DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/concurrency.html#_delegatingsecuritycontextrunnable)

It requires you to define the `SecurityContext` for running the `Runnable` and it will take care of setting up and cleaning `SecurityContext` before and after running the task.

When configuring the `SecurityContext` , it is better to align with the existing used authentication mechanism to define an `Authentication` object that has enough permission to run the job.

Below is a getting started example :

```java
//origin runnable task submitted to Jobrunr
Runnable task = () -> System.out.println("doing some task");

//Configure the SecurityContext that has enough permission to execute the task

SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
// Here it does not matter what values username and password are. Just ensure this user has the the Admin GrantedAuthority and his account is enabled
User user = new User("admin", "password", true, true, true, true, grantedAuthorities);
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);

//wrap the task by DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable
DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable securedRunnable = new DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable(task,securityContext);

//Submit the secured task to Jobrunr
BackgroundJob.enqueue(()->securedRunnable.run());
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution seems very interesting. However, I don't understand how you pass the `DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable` to jobrunr, since the `BackgroundJob.enqueue` method doesn't accept this type. I can't get my code to work.

Comment: I've added the code to give you some context, thanks for your help.

Comment: see my update. seem that you have pass the `JobLambda` or `IocJobLambda` to the `BackgroundJob.enqueue()`

Comment: I have now the following error: `No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.concurrent.DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable' available`

Comment: another problem. better to ask another question

Comment: I'm not sure, because there's some context here, which seems to me to be linked to your solution. I'll look for it myself, thanks for your help.

Comment: I finally created a new question. However, thinking about it, isn't `DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable` suitable in the case where I need to dispatch a job for each of my users? I need the role of the user for the current job, not the role of the person who dispatched the job.